# How to get an instance of an AngularJS Controller after it has been constructed?

Tags: angularjs

I've started to break my application down into separate files due to the size and complexity of said file, based entirely on the way that the angular-seed project has done it.

During this re-factoring I have run into a problem with the way the original controllers were constructed. Some of them, ones that will be injected into a modal dialog are created as instances.

```
var firstInstanceCtrl = ['$scope', function($scope) { code... } ];

var secondInstanceCtrl = ['$scope', function($scope) { code... } ];
```

and used in my 'main' controller this way

```
$scope.buttonClick = function (row) {

    var viewModel = {};

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        backdrop: 'static',
        windowClass: 'modal-wide',
        templateUrl: 'modalFirst.html',
        controller: firstInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            viewModel: function () {
                return viewModel;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {}, function () { });
};
```

but, the way the controllers are registered now, I don't see a way how to get an instances e.g.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('firstInstanceCtrl', [function() {

}])
.controller('secondInstanceCtrl', [function() {

}]);
```

So my question is this, "How do I get an instance of a child controller inside of my main controller?"

Comment: Try to use the string version, `controller: 'firstInstanceCtrl'`, in the `$modal.open`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/provegard/DUrgx/8/ see this for example

Comment: Also, the $controller service could help you out http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$controller

Comment: @EliteOctagon, I had just started reading the $controller docs on my own when you posted this, and the link to the jasmine tests in the fiddle. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the name that was used for the registration of the controller:

```
controller: 'firstInstanceCtrl',
```

`$modal.open` uses `$controller` internally.

Comment: 2 birds with one stone.. Thank you.